ingress-nginx is not stable in EC2 instance
I am setting up a K8s cluster on my 2 EC2 instances: 1 for master node and 1 for worker node. I install K8s my self (not using EKS).
Then I install ingress-nginx to expose my services to the internet.
But the ingress-nginx crash:
NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller-7d8d8c7b4c-m5dtd   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1 (22s ago)   54s

I am using K8s with version:
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.31/deb/ /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.31/deb/Release.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg

Installed ingress-nginx:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.11.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

I am using 2 t4g.small instances.
kubectl get nodes give me 2 node status Ready.
I can deploy another service working fine. Just problem with ingress-nginx.
kubectl logs ingress-nginx-controller-7d8d8c7b4c-m5dtd -n ingress-nginx:
W0927 09:40:01.427863       7 client_config.go:659] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0927 09:40:01.428104       7 main.go:205] "Creating API client" host="https://10.96.0.1:443"
I0927 09:40:01.438718       7 main.go:248] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="31" git="v1.31.0" state="clean" commit="9edcffcde5595e8a5b1a35f88c421764e575afce" platform="linux/arm64"
I0927 09:40:01.753717       7 main.go:101] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
I0927 09:40:01.770164       7 ssl.go:535] "loading tls certificate" path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0927 09:40:01.781383       7 nginx.go:271] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"
I0927 09:40:01.791055       7 event.go:377] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", UID:"1ad56e2d-3e92-4926-814d-c707f44035cb", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"142580", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
I0927 09:40:02.983185       7 nginx.go:317] "Starting NGINX process"
I0927 09:40:02.983277       7 leaderelection.go:250] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-leader...
I0927 09:40:02.983661       7 nginx.go:337] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0927 09:40:02.983873       7 controller.go:193] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0927 09:40:02.992126       7 leaderelection.go:260] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-leader
I0927 09:40:02.992597       7 status.go:85] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-7d8d8c7b4c-m5dtd"
I0927 09:40:03.020665       7 controller.go:213] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0927 09:40:03.020728       7 controller.go:224] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
I0927 09:40:03.020916       7 event.go:377] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-7d8d8c7b4c-m5dtd", UID:"8182dd27-34c0-4538-b8b5-08bdda21734d", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"161398", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0927 09:40:20.357256       7 sigterm.go:36] "Received SIGTERM, shutting down"
I0927 09:40:20.357284       7 nginx.go:393] "Shutting down controller queues"
I0927 09:40:20.365838       7 status.go:135] "removing value from ingress status" address=[]
I0927 09:40:20.365912       7 nginx.go:401] "Stopping admission controller"
E0927 09:40:20.365970       7 nginx.go:340] "Error listening for TLS connections" err="http: Server closed"
I0927 09:40:20.365978       7 nginx.go:409] "Stopping NGINX process"
2024/09/27 09:40:20 [notice] 104#104: signal process started
I0927 09:40:21.386408       7 nginx.go:422] "NGINX process has stopped"
I0927 09:40:21.386435       7 sigterm.go:44] Handled quit, delaying controller exit for 10 seconds
I0927 09:40:31.387400       7 sigterm.go:47] "Exiting" code=0

kubectl describe pod
Name:             ingress-nginx-controller-7d8d8c7b4c-d6zx9
Namespace:        ingress-nginx
Priority:         0
Service Account:  ingress-nginx
Node:             ip-***/***
Start Time:       Fri, 27 Sep 2024 10:09:00 +0000
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                  app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
                  app.kubernetes.io/version=1.11.2
                  pod-template-hash=7d8d8c7b4c
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               ***
IPs:
  IP:           ***
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/ingress-nginx-controller-7d8d8c7b4c
Containers:
  controller:
    Container ID:    containerd://5a0864e316c20e50b02258454367d4e67ccea5285e5457b8f8bf67cfba4c3d49
    Image:           registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.11.2@sha256:d5f8217feeac4887cb1ed21f27c2674e58be06bd8f5184cacea2a69abaf78dce
    Image ID:        registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller@sha256:d5f8217feeac4887cb1ed21f27c2674e58be06bd8f5184cacea2a69abaf78dce
    Ports:           80/TCP, 443/TCP, 8443/TCP
    Host Ports:      0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    SeccompProfile:  RuntimeDefault
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
      --election-id=ingress-nginx-leader
      --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
      --ingress-class=nginx
      --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
      --validating-webhook=:8443
      --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
      --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
      --enable-metrics=false
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 27 Sep 2024 23:45:24 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 27 Sep 2024 23:45:51 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  144
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   90Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:  http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       ingress-nginx-controller-7d8d8c7b4c-d6zx9 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  ingress-nginx (v1:metadata.namespace)
      LD_PRELOAD:     /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
    Mounts:
      /usr/local/certificates/ from webhook-cert (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-kwptr (ro)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   True 
  Initialized                 True 
  Ready                       False 
  ContainersReady             False 
  PodScheduled                True 
Volumes:
  webhook-cert:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  ingress-nginx-admission
    Optional:    false
  kube-api-access-kwptr:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From                      Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----                      -------
  Normal   RELOAD   56m                    nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Normal   RELOAD   50m                    nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Normal   RELOAD   45m                    nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Normal   RELOAD   39m                    nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Normal   RELOAD   33m                    nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Normal   RELOAD   28m                    nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Normal   RELOAD   22m                    nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Normal   RELOAD   12m                    nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Normal   Killing  10m (x144 over 13h)    kubelet                   Stopping container controller
  Normal   RELOAD   5m27s                  nginx-ingress-controller  NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
  Warning  BackOff  101s (x3427 over 13h)  kubelet                   Back-off restarting failed container controller in pod ingress-nginx-controller-7d8d8c7b4c-d6zx9_ingress-nginx(775061a1-52db-43f5-8a04-385c9f71b39b)

